# Substitute a file extension in a zsh alias

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion, zsh-alias

I'm trying to create an alias for `cwebp` to run from zsh that converts an input image file, to an output image file of the same name, but with the .webp file extension:

```
# in .zshrc
alias cwebphoto='cwebp -preset "photo" -short -noalpha $1 -o ${1%.*}.webp'
```

Then in zsh

```
> cwebphoto hello.png
```

Returns a converted file named `.webp`
How can I instead return a file named `hello.webp`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An alias can't take parameters, so your `$1` does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function instead.

```
cwebphoto () {
  cwebp -preset "photo" -short -noalpha $1 -o ${1%.*}.webp
}
```

(In `zsh`, you can also use `$1:r` in place of `${1%.*}`.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious where I can read more about $1:r?

Comment: `man zshexpn`. This and other  modifiers (a single character following a `:`) are documented under history expansion, but they can also be used with parameter expansions